# Reordering dataframe within a list

Tags: r

I have created a list of 10 dataframes with this code:

```
lst <- setNames(replicate(10, sample(1:nrow(CatW),7, replace=FALSE), simplify = FALSE), 1:10)

sampled_W <- lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) transform(CatW[lst[[i]], ], ind = i))
```

giving me this summary:

```
     Length Class      Mode  
[1,] 11     data.frame list  
[2,] 11     data.frame list  
[3,] 11     data.frame list  
[4,] 11     data.frame list  
[5,] 11     data.frame list  
[6,] 11     data.frame list  
[7,] 11     data.frame list  
[8,] 11     data.frame list  
[9,] 11     data.frame list  
[10,] 11    data.frame list
```

I want to extract the data so I can use it to run models but I need to stack the columns within each data.frame into rows to do that i.e. I want to change my output from:

```
Variable 1 variable 2 variable 3 
x           y           z
```

to:

```
Variable  Type
x          1
y          2
z          3
```

I cannot manipulate my individual dataframes whilst they are part of the list, sampled_W. How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Please make your example code reproducible and provide sample data: `object 'catW' not found`.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by `gather`ing the `data.frame`s within the `list` to 'long' format

```
library(tidyverse)
map(sampled_W, ~ .x %>%
                  gather(key, Variable) %>% 
                  separate(key, into = c("key1", "Type"), convert = TRUE) %>% 
                  select(Variable, Type))# %>%
   #if needed to bind the rows and create a single dataset
   #bind_rows(.id = 'grp')
#[[1]]
#  Variable Type
#1        x    1
#2        y    2
#3        z    3

#[[2]]
#  Variable Type
#1        x    1
#2        y    2
#3        z    3
```

#### data

```
sampled_W  <- list(structure(list(`Variable 1` = "x", `Variable 2` = "y",
   `Variable 3` = "z"), .Names = c("Variable 1", 
"Variable 2", "Variable 3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -1L)), structure(list(`Variable 1` = "x", `Variable 2` = "y", 
`Variable 3` = "z"), .Names = c("Variable 1", "Variable 2", 
 "Variable 3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L)))
```